# matlab 2016b ubuntu 17.04

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm using Matlab 2016b on Ubuntu 17.04 and parpool won't work on it, but before updating my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04 parpool was working, I also reinstalled Matlab but it doesn't fix, what should I do?

Comment: Go back to 16.04..... Or ask Mathworks

Comment: It's very unlikely that you'd get any help here as your question is not about programming. Probably [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) are the related stackexchange sites. Contacting  the [Mathworks technical support](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/contact-technical-support.html) would be an even better option in my opinion.